# USB Debugging over Wifi

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I am unable to debug over wifi.

I have followed below steps.

- Go to Android Sdk-> Platform-tools and type cmd
- run adb tcpip 5555
- adb connect and MY IP ADDRESS

Now i got the result show in below Image.

[image]

After my device is connected. I removed my USB cable then i got device list empty.

I have no idea why this is happening.

I have motorola X play Mobile Phone Android 6.0 and having Windows 10 operating System.

Need Help.

Comment: the ip address is not the same of your machine, right?

Comment: @Saret i have wriitten ip address from Setting-> About Phone -> Status. Here i got my phone Ip address

Comment: if your ipaddress is correct there is nothing wrong in your method (I just tested it). Is correct. Try rebooting your smartphone and pc :(

Comment: If you do a lot of wireless debugging, you might find my widget useful: [WiFi Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobiric.demo.wifiwidget).  Shows your IP address.

Answer (score 7):

For simple one click connection of ADB over wifi - You can try using the [Android ADB Plugin from JetBrains](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7983). The plugin will internally handle all the setup and you can click-away and connect to adb over wifi without worrying about anything else. Steps to install and use can be found on its [GitHub repo page](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB).

> Provides an action which allow you quickly connect your Android device
>   over WiFi to install, run and debug your applications without a USB
>   connected by pressing one button.  Connect your device using a USB
>   cable and press the Android WiFi ADB button. Once the device be
>   connected over WiFi you'll see an IntelliJ/Android Studio
>   notification. Now you can disconnect your USB cable and enjoy
>   deploying, running and debugging your applications over WiFi.  The
>   version 2.0 enables a window to check which of your devices are
>   connected or not and connect/disconnect it manually if needed.

**Screenshots from the plugin page:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, both your url and mine are cross linked. Check both page. They have a reference to one another.

Comment: oh, i will check it, actualy i got this link from AS plugins, so just confirming it.

Comment: oh, no sorry, they are different. Both are intellij plugin but by different developers. One i posted is more recently updated though.